# Application Navigation through a single frame

Tags: c#, wpf

I am currently making an c# wpf application in which a task is need to do step-by-step through a single frame, like software installation. Has anyone got idea how to make it?

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it on a recent application I made was to have the main window have 3 parts, a header, the main content, and a footer. Each one had a `ContentControl` that I bound so that in my ViewModel I could change the content being displayed dynamically. In the view model I loaded up the appropriate display based on the state of the program.

If I was at screen Welcome, I loaded up the appropriate header, footer, and content for the welcome screen. The XAML looked like this for each part:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="ContentHeader" Content="{Binding Path=ContentHeader}" Grid.Row="0"/>
<ContentControl x:Name="ContentMain" Content="{Binding Path=ContentMain}" Grid.Row="1"/>
<ContentControl x:Name="ContentFooter" Content="{Binding Path=ContentFooter}" Grid.Row="2"/>
```

In my code then I made new instances as necessary:

```
if (_screen == Constants.Screens.Welcome)
{
    ContentHeader = new HeaderWelcome();
    ContentMain = new MainWelcome();
    ContentFooter = new FooterWelcome();
}
else if (_screen == Constants.Screens.Setup)
{
    ContentHeader = new HeaderSetup();
    ContentMain = new MainSetup();
    ContentFooter = new FooterSetup();
}
```

Each part, `MainWelcome`, `Main Setup`, `FooterWelcome`, etc, are all just user controls I created.

This lets each of the parts have very little to do themselves. Buttons on those panels raised custom events to bubble up to the view model. Like so:

Define the custom event:

```
public static readonly RoutedEvent WelcomeEvent=
            EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("WelcomeEvent", RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
            typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(UserControl));
```

Call the custom event (from a button in this example):

```
private void ButtonWelcome_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Events.TestTintEvent));
}
```

Finally, tie the event to a function in your view model. This can be done in the MainWindow's constructor:

```
AddHandler(Events.WelcomeEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(ViewModel.GetInstance().Welcome));
```

Then I just have the function `Welcome` defined in my view model and do the work there:

```
public void Welcome(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     //Do Work
}
```

This may not be the most optimal way to do it, but it was how I did it, and it worked well in my situation.